# git conflicts with remote, need to keep local changed

Tags: git, bash, windows-10, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I had written some code, then pushed to the master. after some time when I needed to push again (I have added some more code to the same file) I had too many conflicts, because after I pushed first time my code was pulled from someone else and he used resharper to beautify the code and pushed again. So now I have merging conflicts with my modified file and beautified code. 
What I need to do is to pull code from master, then override the beautified code with my code and push it to the master.
I am on windows. Using git bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `backup your current branch for safety` and then `pull master` and resolve the conflicted files using `theirs/ours`.

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git status                       # copy the conflicted file name
$ git checkout --theirs -- .       # accept remote changes if conflicts
or,
$ git checkout --ours -- .         # accept local changes if conflicts
```

Or,

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
$ git branch  backup                                # backup your branch for safety

$ git pull origin master -s recursive -X theirs     # accept remote master changes if conflicts
Or,
$ git pull origin master -s recursive -X ours       # accept local changes if conflicts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there are only beautifying changes and no content changes, just use `git checkout --ours -- path/to/your/file` during conflict resolution to just take your version of the file completely.